# THREE.js: Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, cross-domain, cors

My Chrome version is  31.0.1650.57

I'm learning THREE.js and downloaded a planet sample from https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.planets/

But when I run the earth.html

a strange error happens as the title says:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 59 three.min.js:424
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy. earth.html:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. threex.planets.js:73
(anonymous function) threex.planets.js:73
```

I looked through the code and find something that might be related to this error:

```
THREEx.Planets.baseURL  = '../'
...
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(THREEx.Planets.baseURL+'images/earthmap1k.jpg'),
```

But I don't know how to fix it, I'm relatively new to javascript,

hope someone would help me out!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally
does this help? You need a local server to run texture loading examples locally...

Comment: Yea I've fixed this by running a local server with Node.js, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem by installing Node.js and running a local server to open this html!

Answer (score 5):

Are you running this on a local filesystem (double-clicking the html file) or are you running it on a web server? If you run it on a web server you should avoid the cross-origin permission problems. (This is a security feature of browsers such as Chrome.)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should fix it.

```
var imageObj = new Image()
imageObj.onload = function(){
 THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imageObj)
 // or maybe load image into canvas?
}
imageObj.crossOrigin="anonymous"
imageObj.src = THREEx.Planets.baseURL+'images/earthmap1k.jpg'
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.  I also highly recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, using that link as a reference can greatly help the visibility and clarity of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `crossOrigin="anonymous"` in your image tag as below.

`<img src="SOMETHING" crossOrigin="anonymous" /`>

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't work with loading images through javascript. That's how it works when loading images via javascript, for WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

I konw that problem is you need to run your project or the Three.js example in **server environment**,like the above answer run your code in nodejs or Appserv these local serve